# Mapping lists with Automapper

Tags: c#, automapper

I am using code first migrations for creating entities. My entities look like that:

```
public class User
{
    private string userWholeName = string.Empty;
    private ICollection<UsersInRoles> usersInRoles;
    public User()
    {
        this.UserId = Guid.NewGuid();
        this.usersInRoles = new System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<UsersInRoles>();
    }

    [Key]
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }

    //TODO: check for resource names and for all models
    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = null)]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [MaxLength(30)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UsersInRoles> UsersInRoles
    {
        get { return this.usersInRoles; }
        set { this.usersInRoles = value; }
    }
}
```

My UsersInRolesClass:

```
public class UsersInRoles
{
    public UsersInRoles()
    {
    }

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UsersInRolesId { get; set; }

    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public int RoleId { get; set; }

    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

My Role class:

```
public class Role : Interfaces.IRole
{
    private ICollection<UsersInRoles> usersInRoles;

    public Role()
    {
        this.usersInRoles = new HashSet<UsersInRoles>();
    }

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int RoleId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string RoleName { get; set; }

    public string RoleDescription { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<UsersInRoles> UsersInRoles
    {
        get
        {
            return this.usersInRoles;
        }
        set
        {
            this.usersInRoles = value;
        }
    }
}
```

So those are my db entities. I am trying to map them to:

```
 public class UserDTO
    {

       //other properties same as in User entity

        IList<RoleDTO> Roles { get; set; }
    }

public class RoleDTO
    {
         int RoleId { get; set; }

         string RoleName { get; set; }
    }
```

Every property is mapped, but Roles are not. I am trying this:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<UserDTO, User>().ForMember(dest => dest.UsersInRoles, opt => opt.ResolveUsing(c=>c.Roles.Select(f=>new UsersInRoles() { Role = new Role() { RoleId = f.RoleId,RoleName = f.RoleName}, RoleId = f.RoleId,UserId = c.UserId }))));
```

Any Ideas ?